# I need to use VBA to pull cells into a data structure to work with based on 2 separate values

Tags: excel, vba

I have 4 columns in a spreadsheet in Excel. 3 columns are text, 1 is integer. I need to pull all of the values from the integer column based on the values in the text columns so that I can run a bunch of calculations on them.

For example, I need all of the values of "Count" where the value in the Type column is "Apple", the value in the Quality column is "Fresh" and the value in the Owner is "Jones".

Then I can calculate the average number of fresh apples Jones had each month, the most he had in any one month, and the least he had in any one month.

I'm not finding averageifs, maxifs and minifs functions in VBA, or I'd use them.

Any direction would be appreciated, as I've been banging my head against this problem and trying different solutions without anything working even slightly.

As a note, the number of rows will vary from one run to another, but I have the last row calculated, if that makes a difference.

Comment: `WorksheetFunction.AverageIfs`? Same for the other two.

Answer (score 0):

You may find `AverageIfs` etc. utilizing `Application.WorksheetFunction.AverageIfs`.
Hence, your code might end up something like this:

```
Dim ws as worksheet
set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim avgRange as Range
dim FirstRow as integer
dim LastRow as Long

with ws
    Set avgRange = Cells((FirstRow, Count), (LastRow, Count))
    Set criteriaRange = Cells((FirstRow, Owner), (LastRow, Owner))
    Criteria1 = "John"
    Criteria2 = "Fresh"

     .Range("A5").Application.WorksheetFunction.AverageIfs(avgRange, criteriaRange, Criteria1, Criteria2)
end With
```

Comment: The formatting on the averageifs doesn't make sense to me, and I can't find a good example online.

My columns are numbered with variables to represent their names, and I have FirstRow and LastRow variables defined also.

Is there any chance you might take pity on me and give me the correct code for my example above?

Comment: Of course, but I'd need a bit more information to do so. Arg1 = Range to get average from, arg2 = criteria range 1, arg3 = criteria 1, etc... If that does not help, please provide a sample of your worksheet data, and what what :-)

Comment: So, if I'm understanding right, the following would be the parenthesis after AverageIfs: ((.Cells(Count,FirstRow):.Cells(Count,LastRow)) As Range, (.Cells(Owner,FirstRow):.Cells(Owner,LastRow)) = "Jones"), (.Cells(Type,FirstRow):.Cells(Type,LastRow)) = "Apple"), (.Cells(Quality,FirstRow):.Cells(Quality,LastRow)) = "Fresh"))

Comment: Yes, but exclude the as range part, this was just to specify that the object needs to be a range.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your help!

Comment: I’ve edited my answer above to fit what you wrote in your last comment here. Not sure about all your criteria, but it should do the trick.